# sometimes a field annotated with @ViewById returns null when accessed on UIThread

Tags: java, android, android-annotations, findviewbyid, android-runonuithread

I have a class which uses `AndroidAnnotations` and `@ViewById` annotation. I've seen many crashes because of some of the fields with `@ViewById` annotations being null.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(boolean)' on a null object reference
>    a problem with two of them which

Here's part of the class:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_categories_tab)
public class CategoriesTabFragment extends BaseFragment implements CategoryAdapter.OnItemSelected, SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    @ViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout)
    protected SwipyRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    @ViewById(R.id.placeholder_textview)
    protected CustomTextView statusLabel;

    private void loadChildren() {
        AndroidUtil.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true); //crash happens here, but not always
            }
        });
    }

    categoryService.getCategories(new CommListener<Pair<Category[], Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(NetworkResult result, Pair<Category[], Boolean> object) {
                AndroidUtil.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            statusLabel.setText(""); //another point that crash happens, but again sometime and only in early stage of the fragment's life
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

And this is the AndroidUtil class:

```
public class AndroidUtil {
    private static Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public static void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        mainHandler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Android; and I don't seem to find the reason. I'd appreciate any help, in advance.

Comment: It because fragment you are calling it before fragment call onCreateView

Comment: @Selvin 'm using AndroidAnnotations and everything get called from @ AfterView afterView() method and afterward. Isn't the fragment attached to the Activity in these points of time?

Answer (score 0):

Change `AndroidUtil.runOnUiThread` to getActvity() and check null before using.

In your case, it's crashing because sometimes your fragment is not attached to the Activity so all you layout inside is null.

Comment: 1.how do you mean by change it to getActivity()? 2.All of these methods get called in @AfterView afterView() method doesn't this mean that at this point Fragment is attached to the Activity?

Comment: You are doing asynchronous call, so the response may come with a delay, In that time your Fragment might not be attached to the Activity, So the View object will be null.